# How can I pass date parameter in jmeter http request?

Tags: selenium, jmeter

In jmeter http request text parameter we will pass ${name} like this how can I pass for date parameter

Comment: Plz anybody know the answer reply me

Comment: May be, you can try this
`${__time(dd/MM/yyyy,)} or ${__time(hh:mm a,)}`

Comment: please add some code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: are you taking the date value form csv file ?

Answer (score 0):

No
by notepad .txt file for text i am passing ${name} for date I have tried with ${_dd/mm/yyyy} this format but not accepted. Input file we can us both CSV or txt file

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let us know.

```
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time
${__time(dd/MM/yyyy,)}
${__time(hh:mm a,)}
```